# Catching an exception and continuing with the loop to continue web search with python

Tags: python

I am running into exceptions when i try to search for data from a list of values in search bar. I would like to capture these exceptions and continue with the rest of the loop. Is there a way i could do this. I am getting two kinds of exceptions, one is above the search bar and one below. I am currently using selenium to login and get the necessary details

Error Messages:
 Above search bar

```
our search returned more than 100 results. Only the first 100 results will be displayed. Please select 'Reset' and refine the search criteria for specific results. (29)

Employer Number is not a valid . Minimum length should be 8. (890)
```

Error Message below the search bar.

```
No records found...
```

This is my code:

```
for i in ids:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
        # searching for an id.
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)
        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()
        #navigating to the employee details
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
```

After the above code runs if there is an error or mismatch i am getting the mentioned exceptions and the code shuts down. How do i capture those exceptions and continue with the code. If i code do something similar the way i am capturing the date would be really helpful.

```
        #copying the and storing the date
        subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
        subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
        #exiting current employee details
        driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
        sleep(1)
```

Edited Code:

```
for i in ids:
    try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[16]/td[1]/a').click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a').click()
        # searching for an id.
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_txtEmprAcctNu"]').send_keys(i)
            driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_btnSearch').click()

            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_grdAgentEmprResults"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()
        #navigating to the employee profile
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td[3]/a').click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="print_area"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a').click()
        #copying the and storing the date
            subdate = driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMain_frmViewAccountProfile_lblSubjectivityDate').text
            subjectivitydate.append(subdate)
        #exiting current employee details
            driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_ULinkButton4').click()
            sleep(1)
    except:
        continue
```

How do i restart the loop?
Regards,
Ren

Comment: Have you had a read through the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) before?

Comment: Have you tried [`try, except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) ?

Comment: @Karuhanga yes i did check the documentation. I was getting an error. when i tried `code` except Exception as e: `code`. The message i was getting was cannot find Exception. I have searched to find a solution and i am stuck. Could not find anything that would help me continue with the loop as well

Comment: got it to work using `try, except`. However with `continue` the loop does not restart. Edited code above

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that all your `ids` could be throwing the same exception? Also, avoid generalizing the exception so you can catch only the one you're interested in, first find out the exception type with `type(e)` after catching `e`. `except Exception as e:` should work.